# Break Node.js into debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging

Is this possible to break already running Node.js process that was started normally without any extra flags related to debugging into the debugger mode to inspect some variables for example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you could do something like that in a running server but you always have access to the console on chrome if you want to debug what you render.
You can try to Console.log(varNameHere) the variables you want to see.